# SQL issue with grouping data within the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some patient/doctor data and I need to be able to pull data, based on a date range, of doctor procedures. The problem is that the column where the doctor code is kept is the same column as the procedure code.

The only correlation between the rows is that for every Procedure Code based on a Doctor’s Task there is a corresponding Procedure Code for that doctor. Also, there is a Fee for the task and a corresponding ‘0’ Fee for the doctor.

Example of Data Structure:

```
         Procedure Code          Description
            D1000                   Exam
            D1001                   Filling
            D1002                   Cleaning
            ZZ_Maria                Maria's Patient
            ZZ_Jose                 Jose's Patient

         Patient#          Procedure       Date Completed          $ Fee
            1000              D1000           1/1/2001                23
            1000              ZZ_Maria        1/2/2001                0
            1000              D1000           1/2/2001                25
            1000              D1001           1/3/2001                35
            1000              ZZ_Jose         1/4/2001                0
            1000              D1002           1/4/2001                45
```

So I need a query to show exams done for a specified date range grouped by the coordinator

```
    Date Range Specified:   1/1/2001 thru 2/30/2001

    Date            Coodinator      Name            Procedure       Fee
    1/2/2001        ZZ_Maria        John Doe        Exam            25
    2/10/2001       ZZ_Jose         John Doe        Exam            27
```

And a query that shows all the procedures listed for each coordinator

```
    Date Range Specified:   1/1/2001 thru 2/30/2001

    Date            Coodinator      Name            Procedure       Fee
    1/2/2001        ZZ_Maria        John Doe        Exam            25
    1/3/2001        ZZ_Maria        John Doe        Filling         35
    1/4/2001        ZZ_Maria        John Doe        Cleaning        45
    2/10/2001       ZZ_Jose         John Doe        Exam            27
```

Please Help, Ive tried everything that I can think of. I have no problem getting the data that I want, but I cant get it to come out the way that it needs to.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is the data in TWO tables or ONE table?

Comment: Mixing two types of data in one table is going to be a lot of trouble eventually. If you can't restructure into a separate Coordinator table, write `VIEW`s that separate out the two different interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing info how to get patient name, but otherwise this is the query:

```
SELECT
  p1.date, pr2.description, [name?], pr1.description, p1.fee
FROM
  patient p1,
  patient p2,
  procedure pr1,
  procedure pr2
WHERE
  p1.patient# = p2.patient# and p1.date = p2.date 
  and p1.fee != 0 and  p2.fee = 0
  and p1.procedure = pr1.procedure and p2.procedure = pr2.procedure;
```